# GitLab CI build multiple dockers + test end-to-end

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, end-to-end, monorepo

I want to build and test multiple dockers from one repo in GitLab. This monorepo holds a few microservices that work together.
We have have a working `docker compose up` to aid local dev, so thats a start. 
Goal is move build + test to GitLab, run a E2E test (end-to-end) of these dockers, and let GitLab upgrade our staging environment.

The building of multiple dockers is just multiple jobs in build stage of the (one) pipeline, testing can happen per docker i guess, which leaves testing the whole with multiple dockers running in a (or the?) staging environment.

1. How can GitLab run E2E tests on multiple dockers? (or is this unwise to begin with)
2. Would we need Kubernetes for the inter-docker mapping (network, volumes, but also dependencies) that docker-compose now facilitates?

We are using a self-hosted GitLab CE instance.

**Update:** cut shorter, use proper terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked on PHP, and never done Docker build for multi module, although I tried out a quick example of multi module kind of thing for Nodejs. Check this [Repo](https://gitlab.com/ch4nd4n/multi-docker-example)

Refer to [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/ch4nd4n/multi-docker-example/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) which builds two independent hello world kind of nodejs module.

I now adapted this to build docker images separately.

**Original answer** (question changed 12th July)

You haven't mentioned what documentation you are referring to. You should be able to configure using `.gitlab-ci.yml`

AFAIK Building docker image should be programming language agnostic. If you can run `docker build .` on your local. Following documentation should help 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

You can use Gitlab pipeline for testing < - > building images. Refer to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html

Refer to this for PHP build - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/php.html

Comment: Aware that docker abstracts those concepts, thats why i want to use it. Reading that last one again did help to get my GitLab Runner working, so thanks for that.

Comment: I just realised the term "monorepo" helps describe my problem better, so updating question now..

Comment: Thanks. Nice example project to build two dockers. These could work to quickly test inter-container networking and try a E2E test of multipe running. Still wondering if a monorepo is the right approach for CI right now in GitLab.

Comment: I would suggest against having mono repo. It should be used only as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, 2 years of experience later.

- For a normal (single-project/service) repo the CI is straightforward.
- For a monorepo, an end-to-end test is straightforward.

You can combine these aspects by having a repo with submodules, its essentially both. But this can cause overhead if done continiously and mostly usefull for proofing beta/alpha and release-candidates.

If you know more options, feel free to add here.